# What are some real-world scenarios in which we use late binding?

Tags: java, c#

I'm currently undergoing training at my new job in C#, and I learned about reflection and late binding. I really can't comprehend why anyone wouldn't have access to a class at run-time, and why we would have to use late binding to dynamically create an instance of the same.

Are there some actual real world applications in which late binding can be used? Or is it almost never used? (Ideally, I would like a simplified scenario.)

Comment: Hi Haraesh, welcome to stackoverflow. you question apparently looks like discussion or research base. I guess you should avoid asking such questions here and ask them on other forums. you can learn more about it here
https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Think of addon scenarios. The main program does not and should not know the code/class that will be executed eventually. In such a setup you will have late binding at some point where to context switches from the main applications to the addons code.

Comment: @Ans Bilal Got it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @thehennyy I see... so when a new module is added to the main program, it is referenced in the latter using late binding so it doesn't have to figure out the definition of the addon and instead focus on the common functions? Or something similar?

Comment: The main program does not contain a reference to the addon at all. A direct reference would not require late binding. Its more like late binding is one tool to do the job of allowing code to execute that is not know on compile time.

Comment: @thehennyy I understand. Thanks for the clarification!